# UIViewRepresentable and its content's intrinsic size

Tags: swift, autolayout, swiftui

I've created a `UIViewRepresentable` for `UIVisualEffectView` in order to make certain components vibrant. This works, however it seems to shrink controls vertically at times or just at random alter their bounds at runtime. I can't seem to make it work reliably. I need this to work with any SwiftUI content or even other `UIViewRepresentable` used in place of content. Wrapping the `UIVisualEffectView` inside of a `UIView` and using auto layout seems to help, but other controls (such as a custom `UILabel` wrapped inside of a `UIViewRepresnetable` gets vertically clipped).

```
public struct VibrantView<Content: View>: UIViewRepresentable {
  private let content: UIView!

  private let vibrancyBlurEffectStyle: UIBlurEffect.Style

  init(vibrancyBlurEffectStyle: UIBlurEffect.Style, @ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) {
    self.content = UIHostingController(rootView: content()).view

    self.vibrancyBlurEffectStyle = vibrancyBlurEffectStyle
  }

  public func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIView {
    let containerView = UIView()

    let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: vibrancyBlurEffectStyle)
    let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect)
    let blurView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)

    blurView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    containerView.addSubview(blurView)

    content.backgroundColor = .clear
    content.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    blurView.contentView.addSubview(content)

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
      blurView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.widthAnchor),
      blurView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: containerView.heightAnchor),

      content.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.widthAnchor),
      content.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: blurView.heightAnchor),
    ])

    content.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    content.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    content.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    content.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)

    blurView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .vertical)
    blurView.setContentHuggingPriority(.defaultLow, for: .horizontal)
    blurView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .horizontal)
    blurView.setContentCompressionResistancePriority(.defaultHigh, for: .vertical)

    return containerView
  }

  public func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIView, context: Context) {
  }
}
```

Used as:

```
  ...

  VibrantView(vibrancyBlurEffectStyle: .dark) {
    Text("Hello")
      .foregroundColor(Color.gray)
  }
```

When run on device with other views inside of a `VStack`, you'll see "Hello" clipped partially from the bottom. In Preview, you'll see a much larger blue rectangle (bounds) around "Hello", whereas I'd like this to be hugging the content. The `VStack` does not assume the full natural height of the overall view.

Using `fixedSize()` doesn't work and it produces even weirder results when used with other controls.

Comment: Why the downvote? The "answer" did not help, nor is it applicable in my case where I need to use a `ViewBuilder` for a Vibrant container. The problem remains - I cannot seem to auto-resize my UIKit container around SwiftUI controls properly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After trying various techniques and hacks - I simply could not get the UIKit container (i.e. `VibrantView`) to hug its SwiftUI contents reliably, without adding a fixed sized `.frame(...)` modifier on top - which makes it difficult to use this with dynamically sized `Text`.

What did work for me was a bit of a hack and probably won't work for every generic view out there (and probably won't scale well for dozens of views), but works well for simple use cases, especially if you're hosting this inside of a dynamically sized `UITableViewCell`.

The idea is to use a dummy version of the same view, and set the `VibrantView` in an `.overlay( ... )`. This will force the overlay to assume the same overall size of the parent SwitfUI `View`. Since the view being applied the modifier is a copy of the same view that `VibrantView` wraps, you end up with the correct dynamic size at runtime and in Xcode previews.

So something like this:

```
  SomeView()
    .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
    .overlay(
      VibrantView(vibrancyBlurEffectStyle: .dark) {
        SomeView()
         .frame(minWidth: 0, maxWidth: .infinity)
      }
  )
```

I can imagine turning this into a modifier so that it wraps the above in a single call, but in my case to ensure it remains performant for Images, I'm doing something like this:

```
  Circle()
    .foregroundColor(.clear)
    .frame(width: 33, height: 33)
    .overlay(
      VibrantView(vibrancyBlurEffectStyle: .systemMaterialDark) {
        Image("some image")
          .resizable()
      }
  )
```

Creating a `Circle` is arguably lighter weight compared to the actual image. I create a transparent circle, set the actual size of the image there, and then put the `VibrantView` container into the `overlay`.

Answer (score -1):

why so complicated?

try this:

```
struct Blur: UIViewRepresentable {
    #if os(iOS)
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .systemMaterial
    #else
    var style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .light
    #endif

    init(_ style: UIBlurEffect.Style = .dark) {
        self.style = style
    }

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UIVisualEffectView {
        return UIVisualEffectView(effect: UIBlurEffect(style: style))
    }
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UIVisualEffectView, context: Context) {
        uiView.effect = UIBlurEffect(style: style)
    }
}
```

and use:

```
 Text("Great text with prominent")
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .padding()
                    .background(Blur(.prominent))
```

in general you should not use constraints in UIViewRepresentable -> the size will be defined by parent view like Text in this example or VStack, who gives the right size to the blur. Normally a blur is not standing alone but the typical is a blurred background because you want to put text on it so you can read the text better.

Comment: If you look at my code - I'm not using Blur, I'm using Vibrancy. For Vibrancy, I need the content view to be added to the `contentView` of the vibrant `UIVisualEffectView`. I am not using it as a background, I'm using it as a container, so your technique does not work.

Comment: you are right...what about this. https://gist.github.com/b3ll/ca222a53eef1f4b1319fd02a014718ef

Comment: Just tried that - same issue, moreover I now see a compilation error regarding @objc layoutSubviews not supported by generic classes ¯\_(ツ)_/¯